# Outlook is filling up thin client's disk space quickly

Tags: windows, outlook, disk-space-utilization, outlook-2010, thin-client

I have a number of thin clients at the office. They're on a VM running Windows Server 2008 and Office 2010. The C: drive has 150 GB of space and we use a network storage device for our shared drive where the majority of files are stored.

I ran spacesniffer to see what was taking up the majority of the drive. Spacesniffer identified Outlook as the program that was taking up the majority in the user accounts. I deleted a few users that no longer work for the company or are not using thin clients anymore. It freed up about 20 GB of space. However, I went back to check on the drive, and within 24 hours of freeing up that space, the drive was back to less than 1 GB available.

Any help to clean up some Outlook data would be helpful along with a reason why the drive would fill up so quickly would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It's the OST files... the locally cached copy of the emails and calendar events and such that Outlook downloads from the Exchange server.

[You want to disable cached mode and prevent Outlook from creating an OST file](http://www.slipstick.com/exchange/outlook-online-mode-creates-ost-file/), though why you'd do this instead of just using OWA (Outlook Web App/"Exchange Webmail") is beyond me.

[Both settings are controllable by GPO](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179175.aspx#ConfigureCEMGP) or registry key, so pick your preferred method.

---

These policies will set the following registry values

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\15.0\outlook\cached mode
DWORD: enable
Value: 0

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\OST
DWORD: NoOST
Value: 2
```

`NoOst` value specifies whether or not an OST is created at startup. Setting the NoOst value to 2 will prevent the use of OST files. A value of 3 will allow OST files for cached mode but won't create one when online mode is used.

---